# TDD in Codeigniter: how to mock the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tdd

I am trying TDD in Codeigniter and I'm stuck. I am using TOAST and want to test a simple feature without touching the database...

```
function test_get_products_by_user_id()
{
}
```

How to create a mock of the database for a case like this? I do not want to query the database for such tests.

Comment: TOAST? Why do people invent their own unit-testing frameworks when there is [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html)? It seems so superfluous to learn TOAST when the industry standard is PHPUnit. Does TOAST even support mocking? Doesnt look like it from http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/

Comment: Codeigniter itself, because it uses a front controller and singletons everywhere, is very hard to test with PHPUnit. Toast is custom-made for CI. Not a defense, just an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I wanted to avoid querying a real database, the answer for this is to create a separate database and fill it with dummy data for testing. You can easily switch the database when running the tests - this is written in the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

"The reason we use a multi-dimensional array rather than a more simple one is to permit you to optionally store multiple sets of connection values. If, for example, you run multiple environments (development, production, test, etc.) under a single installation, you can set up a connection group for each, then switch between groups as needed. For example, to set up a "test" environment you would do this:"

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['test']['username'] = "root";
$db['test']['password'] = "";
$db['test']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['test']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['test']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using something like HypersonicSQL?

It will create an in-memory database that will act like your real database.  You do have to set it up each time you want to run the unit tests though.